# Animate iphone tableviewCell background image with two images

Tags: iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

i want to animate tableviewcell background image with two blinking images on didSelectRowAtIndexPath. We can use following code, but it will show one image in background. However I want gif like image which blinks.

```
cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"correctAnswer.png"]]autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageView has the ability to do animation with the `animationImages` property.

```
UIImageView* imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
imgView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"correctAnswer1.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"correctAnswer2.png"], nil];

imgView.animationDuration = 0.5;
cell.backgroundView = imgView;
[imgView startAnimating];
```

You need to have each frame of the animation included in your project, correctAnswer1.png, correctAnswer2.png, etc...

Also, wouldn't it be better to use `UITableViewCell`'s imageView property? That way you would get your animation in the left of the cell and it wouldn't interfere with the text or any other parts of the cell...